# How to implement OPENJSON Having JSON code as a text inside a column. How do i use OPENJSON on the column of a table in AZURE SQL Dataware House?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, open-json

Eg: **RAW DATA**

```
| ORDER# | SUBORDER# |             DISCOUNTS          |
|------- |-----------| -------------------------------|
|   1    |    1-123  | '[{ discount:"1",amount:"1"}]' |
|   1    |    1-123  | '[{ discount:"2",amount:"2"}]' |
```

Want to apply OPENJSON on Discounts and have below OUTPUT:

```
| ORDER# | SUBORDER# | discount |   amount   |
|------- |-----------| ---------|------------|
|   1    |    1-123  |    1     |     1      |
|   1    |    1-123  |    2     |     2      |

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 44
Must declare the scalar variable "@discounts".
```

Comment: Hi @syed ahmed, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my answer, please add `;` after the insert statement.

1. Create table and insert two rows:

```sql
create table dbo.test(

    ORDER# varchar(255),
    SUBORDER# varchar(255),
    DISCOUNTS varchar(255)
);

insert into dbo.test values ('1','1-123','[{ "discount":"1","amount":"1"}]');
insert into dbo.test values ('1','1-123','[{ "discount":"2","amount":"2"}]');
```

2. Then we can use following sql to query the data.

```sql
select ORDER#,SUBORDER#,A.*
from  dbo.test t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.DISCOUNTS) 
WITH (
    discount varchar(255),
    amount varchar(255)
) A;
```

3.The result is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Msg 319, Level 15, State 2, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Hi, did you follow my steps?  You can create a simple test. It works well.

Comment: Hi Joseph Xu, I follow you are steps same as well ,and I tried same as you are data aslo but I cant, if they have any other logic?????

Comment: Did you add double quotes to `discount` and `amount`?

Comment: create table dbo.test(

    ORDER# varchar(255),
    SUBORDER# varchar(255),
    DISCOUNTS varchar(255)
)

insert into dbo.test values ('1','1-123','[{ "discount":"1","amount":"1"}]'),
('1','1-123','[{ "discount":"2","amount":"2"}]')


select ORDER#,SUBORDER#,A.*
from  dbo.test as t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.DISCOUNTS) 
WITH (
    discount varchar(255),
    amount varchar(255)
) A;

select * from dbo.test

Comment: Please add `;` after the insert statement.

Comment: Hi @syed ahmed , Do you have any questions?   If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. Very Thanks! : )